# IE10 treat content="IE=9" as Page Default Standard but not use them by default

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I have site on ASP.NET 2.0. I need to force IE10 to render all pages in compatibility mode IE9. I add meta tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

And I see if I open some page and go to Developer Tools that Document Mode is "Standard" hoverer Page Default is "Internet Explorer 9". My question is: "How to force IE10 render page in "Page Default Mode"?
[Here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/844/ie10compatibiltyscreen.png/) is screen shot.

Comment: I'm confused about exactly what you want to achieve - you place a tag to parse it using IE9 mode, yet you talk about IE10.

Answer (score 1):

Document mode is the rendering and javascript engine that IE uses. Browser mode is the useragent string that it sends to the server.

X-UA-Compatible (as a header or meta tag) tells IE which document mode to use (in your case IE10) but does NOT change the browser mode. This is because the browser needs to have already made a request before it sees the X-UA-Compatible. However unless you are doing server-side browser sniffing (hint, you really shouldn't) this should not be a problem.

If you are doing server-side sniffing it is possible to tell dissect the UA string as there are specific variants beyond the version the browser announces itself but unless you are doing something like analytics this is not going to be worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I try to fix the already fixed issue. Thanks all for reply. Tag `<meta>` works fine, maybe someone finds useful links:

- [how IE9 determinates Document Mode](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Jun/16_IEsCompatibilityFeaturesforSiteDevelopers_1.svg)
- [IE Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/)
- [IE’s Compatibility Features for Site Developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx)